# How to instantiate a vba class and call a method from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba, office-interop

As I guess many are, I'm sitting with an ms access application with a mixture of tables, VBA Modules and VBA Classes. I intend to migrate that application to VB.NET.

However it will take some time and I would like to make use of automation to slowly move the code to VB.NET

Now I can call regular SUB and Functions from my VB.NET application but wonder if there is a way to invoke the methods of user defined objects.

Rough example what I want to do

VBA

```
'Class1
Public Sub Test()
  Print "Hello world"
End Sub

'Module1
Public oClass1 as Class1
Public Sub Init()
  Set oClass1 = New Class1
End Sub
```

VB.Net

```
' Left out the opening of the access db
oAccess.Run("Init")
oAccess.Run("oClass1.Test())
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to port the code/functionality to VB.NET?   I'm not sure if you can call VBA from VB.NET, but it would probably be more work than it's worth, IMO.

Comment: Trying to create an instance of a vba class from NET is likely to involve COM which will complicate things more than if you ported the code, I would think.

Comment: You can try `CallByName`  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/186143

Answer (score 3):

The `Application.Run` method requires a string containing *"The name of the Function or Sub procedure to be run"*  as its first argument.  But *"oClass1.Test"* is neither.

You could work around that issue by creating another VBA procedure which wraps your `oClass1.Test` method, and run the wrapper procedure ...

```vb
oAccess.Run("Wrap_oClass1_Test") ' no parentheses after procedure name

Public Sub Wrap_oClass1_Test()
    oClass1.Test
End Sub
```

I confirmed that approach worked with the rest of your sample code when called from VBScript so I believe it should also work from VB.Net.

Tim's `CallByName` [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145731/how-to-invoke-a-vba-class-from-vb-net#comment52182801_32145731) also looks promising, but I didn't test that one.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I will try a combination of CallByName and the Wrap method. This way I would only need one wrap procedure per object instance. I'll report back